# Extra elements in the path to the picture

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I encountered a problem that when loading a page of a site, one of the pictures does not load. I looked and saw that there are extra elements in the way

[image: Wrong way]

Here is the *valid way*:

[image: valid way]

I thought the link was incorrect, but everything passes correctly:

[image: breakpoint]

So, here is the part of html code:

```
@model ForumHCFE.Models.Forum.ForumTopicModel
/////////////////
 <div class="sectionDescription">
            <div class="forumLogo" style="background-image: url(@Model.Forum.ImageUrl)"></div>
            <p>Welcome to @Model.Forum.Name.</p>
            @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <p>
                    <span>
                        <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
                            register
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </p>
            }
        </div>
////////////////
```

[image]

Comment: Will you show your project's directories? Did you store the images in wwwroot?

Comment: @JerdineSabio yea, sorry. Updated question

Comment: added an answer, try the url with `../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add tilde and slash `../` prior to the URL, this will indicate that it should take a step back 1 directory.

`style="background-image: url(@("../"+Model.Forum.ImageUrl))"`

if that doesn't work, try two steps back;

`style="background-image: url(@("../../"+Model.Forum.ImageUrl))"`